# C++ Optional std::vector argument for function

Tags: c++, vector, default-arguments

I have seen some answers here, but they may not apply here. I have a (member) function that is mostly used with only one argument (the 1st):

```
const std::complex<double> Class::func(const std::complex<double> &x, \
                                       std::vector<double> &y = 0, \
                                       std::vector<double> &z = 0) const;
```

I would like for `y` and `z` to be optional, maybe even based on a fourth argument of type `string`, something like this: `func(  ,  ,  , const std::string &choice)`, but which would let me only pass one argument to the function and the other two not be used. If I do pass `y`, for example, its declaration would have to be done previous of calling `func()`, same for `z`, but I'd like this to be optional, the function can be a bit heavy on the math side and there's no need to add the burden of calculating two additional vectors if they're not needed. Is this possible?

Comment: Well if you can wait your your compiler already has it there is `std::optional`.  Otherwise there is `boost::optional`.

Comment: Pass a pointer instead of a reference and set their default value to nullptr. Then check if y!=nullptr and z!=nullptr in your code and you're done. One small caveat, you won't be able to have parameters after those unless you have default values for them (so your string should have a default value, though you could make it less heavy using a smaller type).

Comment: Do you need to modify y or z from inside the function ? in other word can y and z be of type `const std::vector<double> &z`

Comment: @log0 Yes, when they're used. I need to define `std::vector z; z.resize(x);` before, then use it to be filled with data, which is directly dependent on `x` argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pointers and pass a `nullptr`, check for this..

```
const std::complex<double> Class::func(const std::complex<double> &x, \
                                       std::vector<double> *y = nullptr, \
                                       std::vector<double> *z = nullptr) const;
```

I've defaulted them here, but that's optional...

Comment: Would this require some sort of memory management? As in `delete[]` or similar?

Comment: Unless there's also `new`, somewhere, there's nothing to `delete`. You can only `delete` stuff that you `new`ed.

Comment: if you call this function fith `func(vec1,&vec2,&vec3)` while vec2 and vec3 are local variables not. Only if you allocate them with `new`

Comment: @Nim Your version looks the simplest and most promising. I am trying it now. If it works as intended, I'll choose yours as the answer. Thank you to all for the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Given the use of the `std::vector` however, what does an "empty" `vector` mean? This could be used as the "optional" value you require.

Some notes on the original code; the "null" reference is not valid, i.e. `std::vector<double> &y = 0` does not compile. A pointer could be used in it place, it would not immediately mean allocation are required.

```
const std::complex<double> Class::func(
    const std::complex<double> &x,
    std::vector<double>* y = nullptr,
    std::vector<double>* z = nullptr) const;
```

Function overloads are often an answer for situation such as this; the internals of the functions are defer to each for the final implementation...

```
const std::complex<double> Class::func(
    const std::complex<double> &x) const;
const std::complex<double> Class::func(
    const std::complex<double> &x,
    std::vector<double>& y) const;
const std::complex<double> Class::func(
    const std::complex<double> &x,
    std::vector<double>& y,
    std::vector<double>& z) const;
```

There is also [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

```
const std::complex<double> Class::func(
    const std::complex<double> &x,
    std::optional<std::vector<double>> &y,
    std::optional<std::vector<double>> &z) const;
```

If not available in your standard library, there is also [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: Would passing a `std::vector<double> &`, the intended usage here, for the parameter result in a conversion to a reference to this `std::optional`? I do not believe so.

Comment: That would depend on the caller and how they create the `vector`. If it created in place (in the `optional`), then similar semantics are maintained. If they create it outside the optional, then yes, copies are created.

Comment: Would this even work? You are passing non-const reference to temporary. Maybe _optional reference_ instead of _reference to optional_ ?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot. Good point. The `optional<T&>` doesn't compile for `std`, IIRC, boost was fine with though.

Answer (score 1):

References cannot be optional but there is something called `boost::optional<>`

If you are concerned about copy-operations you should use a pointer instead and use `nullptr` as default.

If you also want to make it dependent on a string at the end you could write a wrapper function

Just add another function:

```
const std::complex<double> Class::func(
    const std::complex<double> &x,
    std::string str,
    std::vector<double> *y = nullptr,
    std::vector<double> *z = nullptr) const
{
    if(str == ...)
        return func(....);
    else
       return func(....); //different call
}
```

Comment: *alternatively you can use emtpy vectors as default ... y = {} ...* only works with `const&` and the OP needs to modify the optional vectors.

Comment: Ah did not see that. I removed the part.